# Android need higher API but dont really need it

Tags: android

I have following Code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

and it says for "setHomeButtonEnabled" that I should put API Level to 14. But if API is less than 14 it doesn't even reach this code. So how can I remove this? Or am I doing somethin wrong?

Comment: if you know for sure that a device below API 14 will never hit that then no you dont need the check but better safe than sorry

Comment: Oh thank you did't find it